# What is nothrow delete in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30hb2y79.aspx) mentions that there're nothrow versions of `new` and `delete`. `nothrow new` is quite a known thing - returns null instead of throwing an exception if memory allocation fails. But what is `nothrow delete` mentioned there?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are probably referring to the raw memory allocation functions `operator new` and `operator delete`.

When you invoke a specific version of placement new-expression (i.e. new-expression with extra parameters; they all are officially referred to as *placement* forms of `new`) and the memory allocation function `operator new` succeeds, but the process fails later for some other reason (the constructor throws), the implementation has to abort the process and automatically release the allocated memory by calling the appropriate version of `operator delete`. "Appropriate version" of `operator delete` in this case is the version that has the same set of parameters as the `operator new` function previously used for memory allocation (except for the very first parameter, of course).

This applies to `nothrow` version of `operator new` as well. When you use a `nothrow` form of new-expression, it calls a `nothrow` version of `operator new` and then constructs the object in the allocated memory. If the constructor fails (throws), the implementation of the new-expression releases allocated memory with the help of `nothrow` version of `operator delete`. This is basically the only reason for this version of `operator delete` to exist.

In other words, the `nothrow` version of `operator delete` exists for very specific internal purposes. You should not normally want to call it yourself and, maybe, you don't really need to know about its existence. However, it is worth knowing that for the reasons described above, whenever you create your own version of `operator new` with extra parameters, it is always a good idea to provide a matching version of `operator delete` with the same set of extra parameters.